# grouping daily data by week - dataframe matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that has multiple rows for each day. I've been able to group by day, so it counts one column's values for each day, but I would really like to do the same thing weekly. The following works for daily data, i cannot get it for weekly:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Type']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=False).legend(title='')
plt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
(df.assign(Date = df['Date'].dt.floor('d'))
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W'),'Type'])
   .size()
   .unstack()
   .plot(kind='bar',stacked=False)
   .legend(title=''))
```

Comment: @BenH - not understand, maybe because missing data sample.

Comment: @BenH - Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I was using .dt.date to remove the time from the datetime series, but to get the code you posted above to work I've had to delete that - so my chart now has the time and date. Is there a way of formatting so the chart only shows the date?